# CMake: Mixing up source and build directory arguments (-S and -B)?

Tags: azure-devops, cmake

I am running `cmake` from an Azure pipeline and am seeing an unusual error.

Here's the output from the script being run (`set -o xtrace` is set to print the actual commands):

```
+ cmake -S /home/user/myagent/_work/86/s/repo -B /home/user/myagent/_work/86/b/build_image_builder -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rfmibuild/myagent/_work/86/b/prefix
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user/myagent/_work/86/b/build_image_builder" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

(Note: additional CMake arguments were removed for clarity, and path names were slightly adapted).

As you can see, it's ignoring the source directory provided by `-S` and interpreting the build directory as the source directory. If I first create the build directory, the error looks like this:

```
+ cmake -S /home/user/myagent/_work/840/s/repo -B /home/user/myagent/_work/840/b/build_image_builder -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/myagent/_work/840/b/prefix
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user/myagent/_work/840/b/build_image_builder" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

This is not the first time I have run `cmake` from an Azure pipeline, but this behaviour is new. There might be something in the pipeline configuration that messes with CMake, but I can't pinpoint it.

Things I have tried:

- Remove the `-S` and directly specify the source directory, same behaviour.
- Remove `-B`: This allows me to specify a source directory, but means the binary directory ends up being wherever.

Answer (score 0):

As I was creating this post and preparing all the required info, I found the solution: A build step earlier in the pipeline pulled in an old CMake version into `$PATH` (3.3) which didn't seem able to handle `-S` and `-B`. Because I had specifically checked the system's CMake version, this took a while to register. I was able to bypass the issue by calling the system's CMake directly:

```
/usr/bin/cmake ...
```